# sql query to get last 4 friday dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get last 4 friday dates from the below table. depends on the user input count will be stored in another table and based on that value i want to get the dates. for example if the count is 5 i want to get the last 5 friday dates.

```
---------------------------------------------
  Id        |           fridaydate
---------------------------------------------
   1        |   2014-08-15 11:46:00.000   |

   2        |   2014-08-22 11:46:00.000   |

   3        |   2014-08-08 11:46:00.000   |

   4        |   2014-08-01 11:46:00.000   |

   5        |   2014-07-25 11:46:00.000   |

   6        |   2014-07-18 11:46:00.000   |

   7        |   2014-07-11 11:46:00.000   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT top 5 datefield
FROM table
WHERE lower(datename(dw, datefield))='friday'
GROUP BY datefield
ORDER BY datefield desc
```

Comment: I tried with the above queries. Iam getting the values repeated. I dont want to get repeated dates. please help.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: @TarynEast more basic SQL than this you won't find. If one doesn't master this, one should really do a course. For quick fixes I will help with an answer.

Comment: Hi nire - I know - it's very basic, and I happen to know SQL, so I'm not asking for me, but *NO*, you can't assume that somebody should do a course. Just last week I helped out somebody who was in 5th Grade and on Stack Overflow. These people are *welcome* here and we should not exclude them just because we happen to have forgotten what it's like to be a beginner... If your SQL is basic, then it will only take a sentence or two to explain why you've done what you did.

Comment: if someone was really interested in learning, they would not ask for a  quick solution to a specific problem. If anyone is interested in learning SQL, I recommend [link]http://www.sqlcourse.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use following format:

```
DECLARE @D INT= 5    -- User Input value

SELECT TOP (@D) *
FROM YourTable
```

You can use above query in your stored procedure like below:

```
Create Procedure YourProcedureName 
  @D int
as Begin
    SELECT TOP (@D) *
    FROM YourTable
    Order by fridaydate Desc
End
```

Comment: you can create procedure and use each value for Top part command.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do:

```
select ca.*
from dbo.AnotherTable a
    cross apply (
        select top (a.FridayCount) *
        from dbo.FridayTable ft
        where ft.FridayDate <= getdate()
        order by ft.FridayDate desc
    ) ca
where a.UserId = @SomeUserId
order by ca.FridayDate desc;
```

Comment: I used all the above queries. But iam not getting the desired output.. I have 22-Aug-2014 thrice in my table. when i execute these queries iam getting the date thrice. Instead i want to get only once. please help me in solving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mythily, `select distinct top (a.FridayCount) ft.FridayDate from dbo.FridayTable ...` - ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP @YourCount fridaydate FROM Table ORDER BY Id DESC
```